# mod_rewrite ignore variable if empty

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Ok so i have a project that has product listing by categories,but also listing all products. I created a pagination for it,that works good. I set up mod_rewrite to work with paging on categories,but i cant manage to set it up for all products. The working one is www.domain.com/catalogue/catid/catname/pagenumber, and i also want to make www.domain.com/catalogue/pagenumber, but mod rewrite comes to problem here.

```
    RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)$ index.php?p=$1&cid=$2&cname=$3&page=$4 [L]
```

and when i try to call second link,he treats that page number as cid. So i want to set up mod rewrite to read what is needed,and ignore cid and cname in this case.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to give you an alternative for this one..

Instead of using regexes, which you seem to have a bit of a problem with still.. There's a much easier way.

If you redirect *everything* to index.php, no exceptions.
Then within index PHP, you can read the current url using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], and it becomes very easy with `explode('/', $url);`' to do all this processing..

It's a much more natural way to do routing.

Answer (score 0):

There is not an ultra reliable way to do this in mod_rewrite.

The most reliable method is check for this in PHP.

There are two main methods:

- One as Evert mentions redirect all to the page in question and decipher the url from there, which is what most do
- two, detect the amount of $_GET vars you receive and judge how the page should react to what it gets within the PHP.

What you ask is not very straight forward, nor very fast in regex so I would recommend slapping this clause onto PHP rather than trying to get regex to do it for you.

Comment: I'll just do the pagination old fashioned way without rewriting it. Thanks for answers.

Comment: Yea prolly best bet, though for SEO friendly URLs I suggest going with Everts suggestion. It's the one that all the frameworks use like wordpress and yii and codeigniter and all that so it is a solid method and well proven.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use two rules, if you're sure you'll never get a link like `catalogue/catid/pagenumber` ?

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?p=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?p=$1&cid=$2&cname=$3&page=$4 [L]
```